# How to return multiple columns and rows from a Vlookup

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have put together a formula that returns multiple columns of data from another worksheet.

However, it only returns the first row that matches the results. How can I get it to return all of the rows that match the results of the `MATCH`?

Current formula is below:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($B$1,'Data Pull'!$B$6:$BM,{4,6,7,8,9,10,50,51,52,54},FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:B, 'Data Pull'!B6:BM, {4,6,7,8,9,10,50,51,52,54}, 0)))
```